# scrape table and save in excel [python, beautifulsoup]

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am totally new to web scraping, can anyone please tell me how can I scrape **trailing returns(%)** table from this website-
https://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/newsnapshot.asp?schemecode=16854  open it in incognito mode,
and save it to excel in the same way as it has been shown.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get("https://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/16854/franklin-india-ultra-short-bond-fund-super-institutional-plan-direct-plan/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table",{"id":"trailing-returns-table"})
columns = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in table.find_all("th")]
data = []

for tr in table.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
    data.append([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all("td")])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

df.to_excel("data.xlsx", index=False)
```

The output will be saved to an excel file.

Output:

```
                                  YTD  1-Day   1-W   1-M   3-M   6-M   1-Y   3-Y   5-Y   7-Y 10-Y
0                          Fund  0.76   0.07  0.20  0.90  2.48  4.59  4.60  7.36  8.24  8.85   --
1  CCIL T Bill Liquidity Weight  2.12  -0.01  0.03  0.14  0.68  1.86  3.74  4.09  4.29  4.79   --
2    Debt: Ultra Short Duration  3.85   0.02  0.06  0.53  1.88  3.36  6.98  6.55  7.19  8.18   --
```

Pandas is easier to save to excel file or csv file and also to analyse data. Else it will take a bit of work to write to excel using openpyxl or xlsxwriter which are internally handled by pandas

Comment: Thank you sir, can you please add comments also, and why we use pandas??

Comment: bro, if i need to append more tables in this data file, how can i append instead of write again.

Comment: Create a pandas dataframe and use `pd.concat`

Comment: in which line bro, can you make an edit and write the code.

Comment: Question for @bigbounty about this code.  There is a url in my table that is not being saved to excel.  Its in the first <td> in each <tr>.  Is there a way to save both the url text AND the href into separate columns?